# Did Masrani really die?

Tags: jurassic-world

In Jurassic World, Simon Masrani flies the chopper into the "*bird sanctuary*".  He apparently dies, but I have a theory that he lived.  It just doesn't make any sense that a new billionaire would take control over Jurassic Park and then *die in the same movie*.

**Is there proof-positive of his death?**

Comment: It seemed a bit jarring that they'd introduce his character then essentially do nothing with him and have him die early on, but I guess that's what they were going for. Usually I'd be suspicious a character had faked their death (especially given possible financial trouble with the park), but in this case there's no way he could really have anticipated the breakout in order to set up the fake death, so I have to imagine it was real.

Comment: I've a new source with a definitive answer. (Spoiler: he's dead).

Comment: “ It just doesn't make any sense that a new billionaire would take control over Jurassic Park and then die in the same movie.” Why not? Billionaire arrogantly thinks he can invent crazy new dinosaurs to make more money, and pays for his arrogance with his life. Most of us movie-watching plebeians like seeing billionaires have a hard time. The billionaires know this, so they make movies where it happens, and become billionaires all over again.

Comment: The only purpose her serves is explaining how come there's a new park, since Hammond already learned his lesson the hard way, and Attenborough had died. I guess they already had the next one sketched out so they knew they didn't need him any more.

Comment: Last time I watched the movie, someone pointed out they probably killed him off just to please those who were not satisfied of the previous movies where the owner didn't die.

Answer (score 13):

Per the film's [official junior novelisation](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Jurassic_World_Special_Edition_Junior_Novelization). He ded.

> *WHACK! A Pteranodon hit the helicopter’s spinning blade. And then
> another. The chopper jolted and spun. Jurassic One crashed through the
> roof of the aviary. Leaving a gaping hole in the ceiling, the
> helicopter plummeted to the ground and crumpled like tinfoil. Before
> it hit, the Indominus ducked out of the broken hole at the base of the
> dome.*
>
> *On the cliff, Claire covered her mouth in horror as smoke billowed out
> of the aviary. “Simon…oh, god…”*
>
> *The employees in the control room reacted to the disaster. **No one
> could possibly have survived that crash.** Her voice breaking, Vivian
> said, “We have a breach in the aviary.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Jurassic World Special Edition Junior Novelization](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Jurassic_World_Special_Edition_Junior_Novelization)</sup></sub>

His death is also confirmed on the [viral website](http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com/the-rise-and-fall-of-masrani-global.html) that Universal has set up to market Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom

> ***When Simon Masrani died, his company lost more than a leader; the
> dinosaurs he loved lost a champion. The power vacuum in the company
> that resulted from that horrific helicopter crash effectively pushed
> the safety of the animals they had created to the bottom of Masrani
> Global’s priority list.** For those who argue that activists should
> stand down and allow the company to clean up their mess, there is
> little indication they have the will to do so – the plan is to bury
> the past, as proven by their callous abandonment of the animals.
> Masrani has had their opportunity to make things right, but they are
> out of time.*
>
> <sub><sup>[THE RISE AND FALL OF MASRANI GLOBAL - http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com](http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com/the-rise-and-fall-of-masrani-global.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Now, on account of this is Scifi and Fantasy, somebody should point out that "No one could possibly have survived that crash" in any other movie means that somebody absolutely survived that crash. Still a good answer.

Comment: I used to say _I won't believe that character is dead until they're buried and the hole fill in_, but then then _Buffy the Vampire Slayer_ happened

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Given that this is a film series that literally has them resurrecting the dead through cloning, the odds of a dead character coming back to life (eventually, in one of the films) seem reasonably high.

Comment: @Valorum "Yes, this asset has had it's instincts honed, we've enlarged and strengthened it's teeth and claws,  now it's a merciless killing machine, we call it the Indomasrani  . . ."

Answer (score 6):

### He is absolutely dead

Even in the movies, [you don't survive a fall, and then explosion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOBuKmhurLw) like he did. He had no opportunity to bail safely and no place in which to bail safely to. He was left no opening to convince us, the audience, of a possible survival, and to bring him back would require a huge suspension of disbelief.

Comment: For the record, they used to do this sort of thing in early Batman serials all the time, showing the characters going off a cliff, then retconning the last few seconds at the start of the next episode to show them getting out.

Comment: @Valorum Not to mention Star Trek (Spock), Star Wars (Maul), Kingsman (Harry), and others. I was initially a bit hesitant in my phrasing, but in the end felt it conveyed the certainty well enough. Batman and the above movies could get away with it, but Jurassic World isn't the kind of movie that would or could.

Comment: Besides, even if he *did* get out, how could he survive in the aviary? He'd get eaten alive (literally)!

Comment: "He is absolutely dead" - as opposed to only *mostly* dead?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Never heard any utterances about true love from him, and I'm pretty sure Miracle Max's cure requires a mouth within which to insert medicine.